# How do i change the resolution of a outgoing hls stream using ffmpeg?

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, transcoding

I am using nginx with ffmpeg to stream my live stream and i want to reduce the resolution of it, but it plays the video in high quality everytime

here's my nginx code

```js
events {}
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;

    application src {
        live on;
        exec_push ffmpeg -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -g 10 -s 300x200 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -ac 1 -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live;
        
    }


        application live {
            live on;

            #turn on hls
            hls on;
            hls_continuous on;
            hls_path /tmp/hls/ ;
            hls_fragment 4s;
            hls_playlist_length 12s;
            hls_nested on;
            record off;

            #disable stream consumption from rtmp

            on_publish http://auth_server:4000/auth;
         }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`hls_continuous on;` makes nginx rtmp store previous streams and always start from the beginning, you are likely seeing your original streams from before you added the video scaling.

Try setting `hls_continuous off;` You might also want to manually confirm if there are any old video fragments inside `/tmp/hls`

Otherwise your config looks good `-s 300x200` is the correct parameter for controlling video resolution.

Comment: yeah i've changed the settings as you've told, and restarted the stream and even checked if the /tmp/hls files are empty, i simply dont see a resolution change, i dont understand why?